# scrapy parse_item not being called for a particular domain

Tags: scrapy

I am try to use Scrapy to crawl Shoescribe. But somehow the parse_item is not called. I try to same code with other website and it works fine. Totally no idea what goes wrong. Any help will be really really appreciate! Thanks!

```
import scrapy
from scrapy import log
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from lsspider.items import *

class ShoeScribeSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "shoescribe"
    merchant_name = "shoescribe.com"
    allowed_domains = ["www.shoescribe.com"]

    start_urls = [
        "http://www.shoescribe.com/us/women/ankle-boots_cod44709699mx.html",
    ]

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('http://www.shoescribe.com/us/women/ankle-boots_cod44709699mx.html')), callback='parse_item', follow=True),
    )

    def parse_item(self, response):
        print 'parse_item'

        item = Item()
        item['url'] = response.url.split('?')[0]

        print item['url']
        return item
```

Comment: Can you double check the code you posted, and maybe try to isolate more the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you already figured it out but here are a few observations that I have made that might  be helpful.

1. `print` statement won't work in your situation, even if the code got executed. Usually you can use the [logging](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/debug.html#logging) command as Scrapy recommended, or you have to turn on the [logging](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/logging.html#scrapy.log.start) so Scrapy will forward all the stdout/stderr to you.
2. I basically copied your code to a brand new scrapy project with modifying the `item` class so it will contain the URL field. Then I ran the crawler using the `parse` and seems like it passed the rule and also used the proper callback function. In the end, it has Scrapyed Items generated. I bet if you write some pipeline the result will be properly generated too.

Here is the output that proved ***your code is working***

[image]